# The colors.xml file does not work in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

iam trying to run the colors.xml file under res/values for the hello world app.

i've put the following code in the .xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="background_color">#00F</color>
    <color name="app_text_color">#FF00FF</color>
</resources>
```

however the string displayed does not have any of the background color or the app text color when i run the app.
Do I have to write the code programmatically also.

Comment: Please post the code where you assign the color to the text.

Comment: In your posted code you are defining the colors, however the Text has no way of knowing that it is supposed to have your colors. Look at Renards answer for an example of how to do that by using the `textColor` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to apply the colors to your views explicitly or create a custom theme if you want to change these settings for your whole app.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/app_text_color"
        android:text="hallo" />
```

Comment: Yes you need to apply the colors to your views explicitly ---- what do you mean by that

Comment: oh iam sorry you mean the main.xml.